# How to create a Docker image from scratch?

Tags: docker

I want to create a Docker image which contains Java and PostgreSQL.  I just want to create an Image to reuse it from anywhere.

From reading [the documentation](http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerrepos/) I don't understand how I can do that.

This is what I tried:

```
user@host:/$ docker run -i -t debian /bin/bash 
root@container:/$ apt-get install postgresql-9.3
user@host:/$ docker ps 
user@host:/$ docker commit <CID> username/postgresql
```

Comment: http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerrepos/ and http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerimages/ — you may want to be more specific about what you've tried and where you got stuck. This is all fairly well documented.

Comment: I have seen these docs but I am not clear about how to make my own image and push it into Repo?

Comment: There is a specific guide on [creating our own images](http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerimages/#creating-our-own-images). And [pushing to a hub](http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerrepos/#pushing-a-repository-to-docker-hub) is also explained. You need to tell us what specifically you don't understand or at which point you got stuck. Right now every answer would just point you to the documentation again.

Comment: @slhck : I want to create my own Image which contains Java + Postgresql and I am not getting it from the document. I just want to create an Image to reuse it from anywhere.

Comment: user@host:/$ docker run -i -t debian /bin/bash                                 
root@container:/$ apt-get install postgresql-9.3 :::   
user@host:/$ docker ps::::
user@host:/$ docker commit <CID> username/postgresql:: these are the steps to create image having PostGres... but I am unable to understand the "debian /bin/bash" why we are running this..."?

Comment: [Create a Base Image](https://docs.docker.com/articles/baseimages/) maybe?

Comment: @slhck=> Correct me if i am wrong... I have to put an image of any Operating system and then I have to install the required environment.

Comment: Yes, in principle that 's it. That's how Docker works :)

Comment: What you are trying to do is simply customize an existing image (debian in your example), not creating one from scratch. So 1) Rephrase the title of your question. You seem to be just starting with Docker. So 2) you should really go through the Getting Started guides without fast-forwarding. If you need a solid Postgresql container, there is more to it than installing a package. So 3) use the official image as a base: https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

Answer (score 0):

Use a Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian
RUN apt-get install postgresql-9.3
```

Then build it with:

```
docker built -t username/imagename .
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use Travis R's approach, with using a dockerfile.
If you absolutely want to do it your way, what you should do after the commands you have already typed in is:

```
user@host:/$ docker images
```

Which should now list something like

```
REPOSITORY            TAG    IMAGE ID       CREATED           SIZE
username/postgresql          be6ac83f7606   2 minutes ago     234 MB
```

This is your docker image that you just created.
If you want to start it run

```
user@host:/$ docker run -[whatever flags you want] username/postgresql
```

Be aware that this is not a particulary useful container to start testing with, since it does not contain a database, no data and no way of actually testing.
A better approach for testing and playing around would be to use the following guide:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/step_one/